# $(SolutionDir) MSBuild property incorrect when Building Sub Projects - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, f#-fake

I am having 10 sub projects , and out of these 10 projects I am building 3 projects in my FAKE scripts , but I am getting an error , i.e. `The imported project

**`"D:\MyProject\Project1\BuildTools\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets"  was no found . Confirm that the path in the <import> declaration is correct , and that the file exists on disk .`**

though the expected target file is not at this location ,currectly it is located at this location 
**`D:\MyProject\BuildTools\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets`** ,

my question is why this is searching the file in wrong location . I think this is an issue with the $(SolutionDir) because the project1 csproj file is at this location
 **`D:\MyProject\Project1\Project1.csproj`**

Below is my FAKE Code :

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
!! "D:\MyProject\Project1\project1.csproj"
  ++ "D:\MyProject\Project2\project2.csproj"
  ++ "D:\MyProject\Project3\project3.csproj"
  |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
  |> Log "AppBuild-Output:"
```

)

Is this possible to give my new SolutionDir while giving path of the csproj file ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing properties using [`MSBuildReleaseExt`](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-msbuildhelper.html) instead of `MSBuildRelease`:

```fs
|> MSBuildReleaseExt buildDir [("SolutionDir", "path-to-your-solution.sln")] "Build"
```

Comment: How is the StyleCop.targets file referenced in each of those csproj files? Is it off of $(SolutionDir) or a harcoded url?

Comment: It is used like 
 <ImportProject="$(SolutionDir)\..\Buildtools\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />